# C++ - pass created object in method

Tags: c++

I have a base class *Shape* and derived a few sub classes like *Rectangle* and *Circle*. All Shapes should be stored in a 2d vector, according to another 2d vector with characters (every character is representing a shape like 'o' -> Circle).

The method *addShapeAtEndOfLine(Shape s, vector* line)* should push the object in the vector:

```
void Game::addShapeAtEndOfLine(Shape s, vector<Shape>* line)
{
  line->push_back(std::move(s));
}

Game::Game(vector<string> game_validate)
{
  for(auto it_a = game_validate.begin() + 2; it_a < game_validate.end(); it_a++)
  {
    vector< Shape > *currentLine = new vector< Shape >();

    string current_line = *it_a;
    for (auto it_b = current_line.begin(); it_b < current_line.end(); it_b++)
    {
      if(*it_b == 'o')
      {
        addShapeAtEndOfLine(new Circle(*it_b), currentLine);
      } else if (*it_b == '#')
      {
        addShapeAtEndOfLine(new Rectangle(*it_b), currentLine);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the header-file i do have a vector like this:

```
vector < vector < Shape > > field;
```

Unfortunately this isn't working because it seems, like the constructor of Circle/Rectangle need a reference:

```
Circle::Circle(char character) : Shape(character) {
}
```

When trying to compile I receive this error-message:

> error: invalid conversion from 'Circle*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

When I use this instead it works (because it's a reference):

```
if(*it_b == 'o')
{
  Shape* c = new Circle('o');
  addShapeAtEndOfLine(*c, currentLine);
}
```

Do you have an idea why this isn't working when I create the object in the method respectively can you tell me what I can do to make it work?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your doing it all wrong.  Look up object slicing.

Comment: What is `b`? What is `Wall`?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning - /edit.

Answer (score 0):

Both your `addShapeAtEndOfLine()` method and your `vector<Shape>` operate with concrete `Shape` objects only, not with any descendant objects.  You are [**slicing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) your objects, which kills polymorphism.  Don't slice!  Your `vector` needs to hold `Shape*` pointers instead.

Also, you have a memory leak in your `Game()` constructor.  You are not freeing `currentLine` or the `Shape` objects it holds.  Declare `currentLine` on the stack instead of the heap, and change it to hold `std::unique_ptr<Shape>` objects instead.  This way, you don't have to worry about memory management.

```
void Game::addShapeAtEndOfLine(Shape *s, vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> &line)
{
    line.emplace_back(s);
    // or: line.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Shape>(s));
}

Game::Game(vector<string> &game_validate)
{
    for(auto it_a = game_validate.begin() + 2; it_a != game_validate.end(); ++it_a)
    {
        vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> currentLine;

        for (auto it_b: *it_a)
        {
            switch (it_b)
            {
                case 'o':
                    addShapeAtEndOfLine(new Circle(it_b), currentLine);
                    break;

                case '#':
                    addShapeAtEndOfLine(new Rectangle(it_b), currentLine);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // use currentLine as needed...
    }
}
```